# Structure of the "close by that"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

What are the structure and meaning of the following bolded phrase? I have a problem with understanding of the two phrases meaning where are connected together, "fairly close by" and "flattened out over time":

> And until just recently, most of us thought the sand had come from an
>   ancient mountain range **fairly close by that** flattened out over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse this as two distinct phrases modifying *an ancient mountain range*:

- a locative preposition phrase *fairly close by*

  The internal structure is ambiguous. I think this may be historically understood as the intransitive preposition *by* modified by the adverb *close*, with the *close* piece further modified by the adverb *fairly*. But the parse is complicated by the fact that the collocations *near by*, *far away*,*close by*, and *far off* have also achieved independent standing as attributive adjectivals—they may actually stand before the noun they modify, albeit usually as the orthographic variants *nearby*, *faraway*, *close-by*, and *far-off*. Consequently *close, near, far*, understood as adjectives, are felt by most speakers to 'head' these phrases.
- a relative clause *that flattened out over time*

Paraphrase:

> ... the sand had come from a nearby mountain range which had flattened out over time.